# How can I dual boot CentOS and Windows 10?

Tags: centos, system-installation

I'm using Windows 10 and I have four drives (C,D,E,F). The C Drive is for Windows and has 5.35 GB free. 
I want to install CentOS 7 in C or D drive and dual boot.
What's the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Cent OS recomends minimum 2 GB of disk space. So you can chose if you install ist on C or D drive. To install it on C it would be best to change partitioning and then start the installation.